# Dynamic Binding best approach in OOP

Tags: oop, polymorphism, late-binding

I have some classes in c++. with some hierarchy of base class and some derived classes.
There are some methods in the some derived classes that does functionality for that particular derived class and the other classes do not need any implementation of those methods. So i left them as empty implementation. (All of these functions are virtual)

Now my question is that what are the best practices in OOP while calling such a method with base class pointer in your program. I mean first check the type of reference stored in the base class pointer and then call the method or call the method in any way as the implementation of that particular method in other classes in empty.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, run-time polymorphism is achieved through **virtual** functions. [More info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function)

Comment: yes at least i know that. I think its not that important to mention that these functions are virtual as it is a very obvious thing any how i have updated the above query.